# Escaping a CSV file before LOAD INFILE to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working on a script that routinely uploads a CSV file into a MySQL database. The issue is that one of the fields in the CSV file contains user generated text, which may include quotations and other characters which are unfriendly to MySQL.

I have determined that the most efficient way to upload the CSV file is via MySQL's 'LOAD DATA INFILE' command. Here is the command as it appears in MyPHPAdmin when I upload the CSV:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/myfolder/tmp/property_re_1.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE `markers`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' # 2 rows affected.
```

Simply loading the CSV with this command does not work, as the process terminates as soon as it runs into a '"' and the "ESCAPED BY '\'" doesn't appear to be serving its purpose.

In this case, I think I may have to escape the quotations in the CSV file programmatically with PHP first. Then load the "Escaped" file into MySQL with the LOAD DATA INFILE command in SQL.

I am sure this is a common problem that has a "best practice" solution. Essentially, my script needs to "clean up" a CSV file before loading it into a MYSQL table.

Here is a link to the actual SQL table and CSV file I am working with to help wiser minds wrap their heads around this one: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4iq10i51qlqyq8q/UjEQwvXKDA

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Which code is generating the CSV?  If the CSV is generated properly, there won't be any problem.  If the CSV is not generated properly, it is probably simplest to fix the CSV generator.  If the file is user-defined, then you have a lot more than just the one field to worry about.

Comment: The CSV is generated by an external database which I cannot alter,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data file on your dropbox has fields delimited by `,`, optionally enclosed by `"`, lines delimited by `\n` and containing a header row; whereas your statement above is for a file with fields delimited by `;`, always enclosed by `"`, lines delimited by `\r\n` and not containing any header row.

That said, it's also for a file named `data.csv` whereas the one on Dropbox is named `property_re_1.csv`.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `markers` (
    ->   `L_ListingID` int(20) NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_Class` int(5) NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_Type_` int(10) NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_Status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_AskingPrice` float NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_Remarks` text NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_Address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_City` text NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_State` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ->   `LO1_OrganizationName` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
    ->   `LA1_AgentLicenseID` int(20) NOT NULL,
    ->   `LA1_UserFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ->   `LA1_UserLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ->   `L_PictureCount` int(4) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`L_ListingID`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'property_re_1.csv' 
    -> REPLACE INTO TABLE `markers`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
Query OK, 315 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 315  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```